# Is "$\prec$" a formal math symbol?

Tags: calculus, notation

Is "$\prec$" a formal symbol?

[image]

I've never seen it before.

Comment: Do you mean $\prec$?  In Latex it's \prec.

Comment: It is used for example here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3766205/42969. – Another (perhaps more common) notation is $f(n) = o(g(n))$.

Comment: Is it a formal math symbol? Of course it is. You saw it formally defined. Is it generally accepted (which I think is the question you actually wanted to ask)? Also yes.

Comment: You would more often see it right now as $f\ll g$, or $f\in o(g)$ or $f(n)=o(g(n))$ (as $n\to\infty$).

Comment: It's often used to replace $<$ for a general (partial or total) order, with $\preceq$ used to replace $\leq$. If I saw it without further context, I wouldn't assume it had the meaning given in the quoted definition (which is more often written as $f = o(g)$ as $n\to\infty$, and that I wouldn't expect to have explained by the author).

Comment: Any kind of [majorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorization) is often denoted by $\prec$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio $f\ll g$ generally doesn't mean the same thing as $f=o(g)$.

Comment: @GregMartin That comes as a surprise to me. What would its standard meaning be?

Comment: In analytic number theory for instance (where $\ll$ is very common), $f\ll g$ means that $|f/g|$ is bounded above—so weaker than $f=o(g)$.

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking about what the symbol is typically used for, and what sort of precedence there is for the use of it, then the following would be my answer:

Generally when $\prec$ is used, it denotes some type of abstract order relation, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_theory.

Like in your above example, we give some order to the function by defining an order relation given by the convergence criteria.

Answer (score 1):

In mathematics, you are allowed to introduce any symbol you like, and to define that symbol, and to apply that definition. So, for example, perhaps I wish to introduce the notation $@\!!\!\!\!<$ for a binary relation on the natural numbers. Then I have to tell you the definition of that relation:

> $m \, @\!!\!\!\!< \, n$ means that $m^2 + 3n$ is a prime number.

Great!

And silly, yes... I can't dream of what it could be applied to.

But my point is, that's how notations and their definitions work throughout mathematics.

If you look at the screen shot in your own post, you'll see that's exactly what's going on: that passage is introducing the notation $\prec$ for a binary relation on the set of functions of $n$, and it is telling you the definition of that relation:

> $f(n) \prec g(n)$ means that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = 0$.

And there are *many* important applications of this relation.